# Getting SQL Azure database replication role in C#

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sdk-.net

I am trying to check the replication role of a SQL Azure database using the Azure SDK for .NET.

I used the `SqlManagementClient` to fetch databases from our subscription but there are no properties indicating the replication role.

I used the following code to fetch databases.

```
var client = GetSqlManagementClient();

var database = client.Databases
    .List("<serverName>")
    .First(x => x.Name == "<databaseName>");
```

Is there another way to get this information that I am missing?

Comment: does this help :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt600929.aspx

Comment: Yes I found it earlier but looks like it's not implemented in the client yet. I guess I'll have to write it ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you means to read secondly location, I think Azure ARM management could help us to do this. I have tried it on my local and get the result as followings:

[image]

**[Update]**

Here is my test code:

```html
  public async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            string test;
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adInfo.AuthUrl + adInfo.Telnant);
            ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(adInfo.ClientId, adInfo.ClientSecret);
            try
            {
                result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(adInfo.Resource,cc);               
                test = result.AccessToken;
                return test;
            }
            catch (AdalException ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }   
        }

        public async Task GetSQLInfo()
        {
            string token = await GetToken();
            var sqlclient = new SqlManagementClient(new TokenCloudCredentials(adApplication.Subscription, token));
            var data = await sqlclient.Databases.GetAsync("jatestgroup", "jaserver", "jasql");
        }
```

Here is my class about adInfo and adApplication:

```html
  public class AdInfo
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "clientid")]
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "clientsecret")]
        public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "returnurl")]
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "telnantid")]
        public string Telnant { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "authurl")]
        public string  AuthUrl { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "resource")]
        public string Resource { get; set; }

    }
    public class AdApplication
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ARMTemplate")]
        public AdInfo Application { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "subscription")]
        public string Subscription { get; set; }
    }
```

My Json Settings:

```html
{
  "ARMTemplate": {
    "clientid": "****",
    "clientsecret": "****",
    "returnurl": "http://localhost:20190",
    "telnantid": "****",
    "authurl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "resource": "https://management.core.windows.net/"
  },
  "subscription": "***"
}
```

Since this issue is more related with Auth failed. I would suggest you create a new thread and give more info for us if my code does not give you help.

Comment: Could you share the code that you used in your example? Is it with the `SqlManagementClient`?

Comment: I've been able to use it using `TokenCloudCredentials`. However, it returns us the default secondary location but not the role if the database itself.